# Styling the Xceed ColumnManagerCell

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid, xceed

I'm interested in styling the column headers on an Xceed DataGrid.  The goal is to make the background color grey, with a dark grey border around each header column cell.  It seemed to me like the best way to do this was to style the ColumnManager:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type xcdg:ColumnManagerCell}">
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ColumnManagerCellTemplate}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#c5c5c5"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,1,1,1"/>
</Style>
```

Using this template:

```
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ColumnManagerCellTemplate" TargetType="xcdg:ColumnManagerCell">
        <Grid Background="LightGray" >
            <xcdg:DataCell Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           Background="LightGray"
                           HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                           VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                           BorderBrush="DarkGray"
                           BorderThickness="2"/>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

The background color shows up correctly, as does the content, but I cannot get a dark grey border to show up around each cell.  (Or any color border at all.)  What am I missing?  Shouldn't the BorderBrush and BorderThickness properties control this?  They seem to work on the rest of the cells in the grid, but not the ColumnManagerCells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a border instead of the grid and then hook up the template bindings for the border like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type xcdg:ColumnManagerCell}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#c5c5c5"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,1,1,1"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.Content}"
                                    ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.ContentStringFormat}"
                                    ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.ContentTemplate}" />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I should mention that my default ControlTemplate for ColumnManagerCell is a ContentPresenter instead of DataCell like below:

```
<xcdg:DataCell Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
```

Are you sure your using the correct control template?

Comment: That worked great!  Thank you.  I didn't realize that you didn't have to have a grid inside of the ColumnManagerCell - I was just imitating what I could see of the UI layout using WPF Inspector.